# Groovy: Losing scope on $it when inside of shouldFail()

Tags: groovy

I have this groovy code that checks to see if a software version string is the correct format when instantiating a new Build object. I have a list of invalid build strings I want to test. Below is my test code. I believe this test fails because I lose the scope of "it" inside of shouldFail.  I believe this is true because the value of "it" is always null if I print it from inside the shouldFail.

```
void testInValidBuildStrings() {

      ['4.0..','10.0','11.0. 0.1234-8','9.-.1.1.1','9.foo.0.1'].each {
              shouldFail { 
                    println it //always null
                    Build test = new Build("productName", it, "123456")};         
              }
 }
```

This 2nd version of the case below works (I assume) because I've first assigned "it" to variable called build. I think the scope of it must have changed inside of the shouldFail() but I'm not sure if that's what happening.

```
void testInValidBuildStrings() {

      ['4.0..','10.0','11.0. 0.1234-8','9.-.1.1.1','9.foo.0.1'].each {
              def build = it;
              shouldFail { Build test = new Build("productName", build, "123456")};         
      }
 }
```

Is there a more elegant / correct solution than what I've done below when trying to iterate over a shouldFail()? Truth be told, the extra line to define build is bugging me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. Just name the closure's argument:

```
void testInValidBuildStrings() {

      ['4.0..','10.0','11.0. 0.1234-8','9.-.1.1.1','9.foo.0.1'].each { el ->
              shouldFail { 
                    println el 
                    Build test = new Build("productName", el, "123456")};         
              }
 }
```

`shouldFail` has its own `it` - thus you need to distinguish them.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply. I figured there had to be something built in that I was missing! FYI - I up-voted this answer but I guess my votes aren't visible yet as a new user.

Comment: @Damon, you've too little points to upvote bo please accept my answer.

Comment: Apologies for the delay Opal. I was apparently confused about the difference between upvoting and accepting. Should be all set now.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you have 2 nested closures here.  And each closure have the default variable 'it' defined. Within the shouldFail closure, that instance of it has no value. You can solve this by naming the variable from the first closure and use that instead of 'it' within the second closure.

```
closure {varName->
  secondClosure {
   println "$varName is not equal to $it"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You show the following as working code:

```
void testInValidBuildStrings() {

    ['4.0..','10.0','11.0. 0.1234-8','9.-.1.1.1','9.foo.0.1'].each {
        def build = it;
        shouldFail { 
            Build test = new Build("productName", build, "123456")         
        }
    }
}
```

I would simplify that to something like this:

```
void testInValidBuildStrings() {

    ['4.0..','10.0','11.0. 0.1234-8','9.-.1.1.1','9.foo.0.1'].each { build ->
        shouldFail { 
            new Build("productName", build, "123456")      
        }
    }
}
```